# _aaLen may throw (again) on DMD git master

Tags: exception, associative-array, dmd

I just noticed that

```
 Error: '_aaLen' is not nothrow
```

has returned on DMD git master.

This doesn't happen in 2.065.0-rc1.

Is this by accident or by design?

See also: http://forum.dlang.org/thread/veafqhtptjakiewkwzme@forum.dlang.org#post-veafqhtptjakiewkwzme:40forum.dlang.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed on DMD Git master as of 2 mars, 2014.